# Problem with calculating the block height

Tags: html, css, markup

The problem is with calculating the height of the ext-inner block, this block is supposed to count 100% of the height of the parent block, but something does not work. I expect that the scroll will work in the ext-inner block and I am trying to calculate the correct height of the block using max-height: calc(100% - 100px)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
 
    <style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
 
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
 
    .wrapper {
        height: 100%;
    }
 
    .block {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
 
    .content {
        height: 80%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
 
    .content .base {
        height: 100px;
    }
 
    .content .extended {
        max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
        height: min-content;
    }
 
    .extended .ext-header {
        height: 100px;
    }
 
    .extended .ext-inner {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
        height: min-content;
    }
 
    p {
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="base block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia vitae praesentium, laborum atque repellat debitis accusamus temporibus saepe hic perferendis? Quaerat nesciunt, qui non perferendis sed, adipisci saepe iste aliquam? </div>
            <div class="extended block">
                <div class="ext-header">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui recusandae minus deleniti nemo laudantium aliquam sunt, eligendi, debitis, voluptatem earum tempore repudiandae perferendis dolorum magni molestias sapiente veritatis unde! Ratione.
                </div>
                <div class="ext-inner">
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: replaced max-height with height in .content .extended

Comment: any percentage in height OR max-height OR min-height require the parent to have **height** (explained in the duplicate)

Comment: Please see my example in full page

Comment: Thanks for the answer **Temani Afif**

Yes it works but I need the block ext-inner to decrease in height when the number of elements p is for example 2

Comment: there is also a solution in the duplicate, read the accepted answer until the end

Comment: Thank you again **Temani Afif**, I was able to solve my problem using flexbox, just wondering if it would be possible to do without flexbox...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235017/discussion-between-i-like-cola-and-temani-afif).